# pumping lemma question

Tags: algorithms

SO i have to prove that the following language is not regular {w ∈ {a, b}∗: #a ≥ #b}.

Now i understand that we need to start by assuming that it is regular, and then say something like use S=a^(p+1) b^p, and we know that the xy part will conist of a's, so if we pump it we will have more a's the b's, am i missing something here.

Comment: You’re forgetting that after you decompose your word into $xyz$ satisfying certain conditions, $xy^kz$ has to be in $L$ for all $k\ge 0$. Note that $0$: you can end up with a shorter word than you started with.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the pumping lemma, it seems (as almost always) to be much easier to use the Myhill-Nerode theorem:

$\mathtt a^n$ and $\mathtt a^m$ are distinguishable for all $n>m$ because $\mathtt a^n\mathtt b^n$ is in the language but $\mathtt a^m\mathtt b^n$ isn't.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Henning that the [Myhill-Nerode theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem) is probably the easiest way to show that $L=\{w\in\{a,b\}^*:|w|_a\ge |w|_b\}$ is not regular, but you can certainly also use the pumping lemma. Let $p$ be the pumping length, as start with $s=a^pb^p$, not $a^{p+1}b^p$.

The pumping lemma now says that $s$ can be decomposed as $xyz$ in such a way that $|xy|\le p$, $|y|\ge 1$, and $xy^kz\in L$ for each $k\ge 0$. Since $|xy|\le p$, we know that $xy$ is $a^n$ for some $n\le p$: all of the $b$s in $s$ must be in the $z$ part. Thus, $x=a^r$ and $y=a^s$ for some $r,s\ge 0$, such that $r+s=n$, and $s\ge 1$ (because $|y|\ge 1$). Thus,

$$s=xyz=\underbrace{a^r}_x\underbrace{a^s}_y\underbrace{a^{p-n}b^p}_z\;.$$

We can now say exactly what $xy^kz$ is for each $k\ge 0$:

$$xy^kz=a^r(a^s)^ka^{p-n}b^p=a^ra^{ks}a^{p-n}b^p=a^{p-n+r+ks}b^p=a^{p-s+ks}b^p=a^{p+(k-1)s}b^p\;.$$

If $k\ge 1$, this has at least as many $a$s as $b$s and is therefore in $L$, but if $k=0$, it’s $a^{p-s}b^p$. And $p\ge 1$, so $p-s<p$, and $a^{p-s}b^p\notin L$. Thus, $L$ cannot be regular: it’s not true that $xy^kz\in L$ for **all** $k\ge 0$.

Normally one wouldn’t go into nearly so much detail. One might just say that $xy$ must consist entirely of $a$s, at least one of which is in $y$, so that $xz$ (i.e., $xy^kz$ with $k=0$) still has $p$ $b$s but fewer than $p$ $a$s and therefore is not in $L$. When you’re just starting, though, it can be useful to write out and see exactly what’s going on.

It’s easy to forget that $k=0$ is one of the possibilities, and that in this one case the pumping lemma pumps *down*, not up. However, precisely because the $k=0$ case often behaves a bit differently from the $k>1$ cases, it’s a good idea to look at it specifically.